# Multi select Contact page in Event VF page

Tags: visualforce

I need to create one custom multi select contact vf page for Custom event page. 
I am creating one custom event page where we need to select multiple contact with one event, as of now from standard page it is possible to select multiple contact but with custom event page it's not possible.
So we need to create custom contact multiselect page, which can add multiple contact to one single event.
Like the below screen shot:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this one, it will give you an idea.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html